# parse a query-string in multi-dimensional array format to actual array

Tags: arrays, go, query-string

I am trying to create an extensive search url with this format `?filter[1][field]=brandId&filter[1][operand]=>&filter[1][values][]=firstvalue` but I cant seem to figure out a way to convert this (string) to an actual array (map/slice or anything i can loop on).

i have read a lot of documentation and searched on google but cannot find a good way to do this.

Comment: You are looking for [`net/url.Values`](https://godoc.org/net/url#Values).

Comment: hmm lemme try, though i dont thinks it does that but I may be wrong

Comment: @TimCooper sorry i dont see how your suggestion can convert my string to array.

Comment: @TimCooper can you provide an example https://play.golang.org/p/51b5XgUTsp

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/Or28JJOaUg

Comment: @TimCooper i need to loop on `filter` i do not know how many values might be there.

Answer (score 0):

You could range on the parsed query like so if your `filter` is going to be an unknown length:

https://play.golang.org/p/NSQ7bnJXef

```
    v, err := url.ParseQuery("filter[1][field]=brandid&filter[1][operand]=>&filter[1][values][]=firstvalue&filter[2][field]=brandid&filter[2][operand]=>&filter[2][values][]=firstvalue")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    for id, thing := range v {
        switch {
        case strings.Contains(id, "field"):
            log.Printf("Field Value: %v", thing)
        case strings.Contains(id, "values"):
            log.Printf("Values Value: %v", thing)
        case strings.Contains(id, "operand"):
            log.Printf("Operand Value: %v", thing)
        }
    }
```

But IMO, there has to be a better way than doing the query you're doing now.

Comment: i want the end result a multidimensional map which i can loop and make `brandid == firstvalue`